# Reference book on inference

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, statistical-inference, book-recommendation

Is there a book on inference considered as THE reference one? (a book which explains every important concept, it's not need to try to cover everything if it would be possible)

I need a book to try to read from beginning to the end without worrying if I'm missing something important and use it to review the subject if I forget something.

Inference is a huge subject and sometimes I feel confused what to study

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but [Computer Age Statistical Inference](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI/) by Efron and Hastie is one book to be aware of.

Comment: @littleO Thank you for the suggestion, I will give it a try!